# Return one message for each output on Node-RED function block

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

In Node-RED, how do I return multiple messages on function blocks, one for each output?

I tried this based on documentation, with no success.

```
msg1 = "1"
msg2 = "2";
msg3 = "3";

msg.payload = [msg1, msg2, msg3];

return msg
```

[image: Function block with 3 outputs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return objects not just strings so firstly you need to build objects with payload keys

```
msg1 = {payload: "1"}
msg2 = {payload: "2"};
msg3 = {payload: "3"};

msg = [msg1, msg2, msg3];

return msg;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. With that code I get: "[ [ "1" ], [ "2" ], [ "3" ] ]" on the first output..

Answer (score 0):

```
var msg1 = { payload:"@" + msg.tweet.user.screen_name + "first out of output 1" };
var msg2 = { payload:"@" + msg.tweet.user.screen_name + "second out of output 1" };
var msg3 = { payload:"@" + msg.tweet.user.screen_name + "third out of output 1" };
var msg4 = { payload:"@" + msg.tweet.user.screen_name + "only message from output 2" };
return [ [ msg1, msg2, msg3 ], msg4 ];
```

Comment: That won't work, that returns msg 1,2,3 on the first output and msg4 on the second, which is not what the question asked